# What steps do I have to take to use React-native-Payments with CRNA (project template based on expo)?

Tags: react-native, android-pay, applepay, create-react-native-app

I know that react-native-payments is already cross-platform but it does require certain steps like activating apple pay from the ios project and similar changes for Android.

I wanted to know if there is a way to integrate payments without having to create ios and android modules (react-native init).

Answer (score 2):

Currently no, you will have to eject, and if you do so better consider Payments guide by Expo [Here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments)